# Template metaprograming in Armadillo

Tags: c++, templates

I want to use Armadillo library to computation in my ray tracing project. I read somewhere, that i can use own vector class to pass it to Armadillo, using template programing, but i coudn't find any more information. I want to this, because i want to ommit using a table operator.

TL;DR I want to use Armadillo like GLM

```
arma::vec3 orig;
orig.x = 12.f;
orig.y = 13.f;
```

Where in GLM:

```
glm::ivec3 vec;
vec.x = ...;
vec.y = ...;
```

I think about macro, but its not elegant solution. Additionaly, i must use armadillo, so proposing to use GLM falls

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Have you tried `orig[0] = 12.0; orig[1] = 13.0;` ?

Comment: Yes and its working, but i want to ommit this - orig.x, orig.y, orig.z is more clearly and easier to read and fix code

Answer (score 0):

I forget to add answer earlier:
I copy overloaded operator [] and change it to this form (Col_meat.hpp file) and do the same for y, z, w (changing index of course)

```
   template<typename eT>
   template<uword fixed_n_elem>
   arma_inline
   arma_warn_unused
   eT&
   Col<eT>::fixed<fixed_n_elem>::x(void)
   {
          arma_debug_check((0 >= fixed_n_elem), "Col::x(): index out of bounds");

          return (use_extra) ? mem_local_extra[0] : Mat<eT>::mem_local[0];
   }

   template<typename eT>
   template<uword fixed_n_elem>
   arma_inline
   arma_warn_unused
   const eT&
   Col<eT>::fixed<fixed_n_elem>::x(void) const
   {
          arma_debug_check((0 >= fixed_n_elem), "Col::x(): index out of bounds");

          return (use_extra) ? mem_local_extra[0] : Mat<eT>::mem_local[0];
   }
```